# Watcher does not catch array value changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple array structured like the following:

```
dates[2]
  0:"2018-01-09T15:00:00.000Z"
  1:"2018-01-10T14:00:00.000Z"
```

And my watcher is set up like this:

```
data() {
    return {        
        dates: [],
    }
}

watch: {
    // whenever dates changes, this function will run
    dates: {
        handler: function(before, after) {
            console.log('dates is changed');
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

The only time changes are "watched" is when a array element is added or removed, but not when the value (the time) changes.

How can I accomplish this behavior?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

> When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

> To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

// Array.prototype.splice
example1.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

> To deal with caveat 2, you can use splice:

```
example1.items.splice(newLength)
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats